# Is it necessary to make QDomElement created by the same QDomDocument to write XML?

Tags: c++, qt, dom, io, tree

I use QDomDocument to write XML document.
But in my dom tree, some nodes are created using docA, some using docB.

```
QDomElement parentNode = docA.CreateElement("name");//created by docA
QDomElement childNode = docB.CreateElement("value");//created by docB
parentNode.appendChild(childNode);//in onr tree
```

And:

```
QTextStream out(&file);
docA.save(out, Indent);//docA created the root QDomElement
                       //write the file using docA
```

So is it possible to write the whole tree to XML like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should avoid this because things will start going wrong when if docA goes out of scope if docB is still being used. I believe what you're proposing will technically work until that occurs, but the library seems designed to discourage it.

However, there is a function QDomDocument::importNode() which is probably what you want. You can do something like this:

```
docAParent.appendChild( docA.importNode( docBNode, true ) );
```

The boolean argument controls whether or not a deep copy is made.

See the documentation: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdomdocument.html#importNode